# How to sync two Gmail accounts

Tags: gmail, google-account, email-forwarding

I have my college Id, collegeid@college.com (hosted on google apps) and a personal gmail id, username@gmail.com

I created forward-to address in collegeid@college.com as username+college@gmail.com
Also created send-mail as "collegeid@college.com" in "username@gmail.com".

Now, I am getting all college emails to personal inbox. However, there are few concerns

1. I added fwd address as "username+college@gmail.com". When I get my college email in personal inbox, I don't see this address anywhere! I see the to-address as "collegeid@college.com". So, where does my "username+college@gmail.com" appear? what's the use of +college?
2. When I send an email from "collegeid@college.com" via username@gmail.com, I don't see that mail in "college account sent box"! Without that sync.. Its terrible for me.. say sometime later, I decided to remove forwarding and I don't see my past-emails in my college inbox.